# OAuth2.0 server to server authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, web-applications, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a GAE application & service. To authenticate users is relatively easy, however, I'm not exactly sure how I authenticate servers which want to use my services. Specifically, I have another server which will access the services. I'm using Google login for authentication (OAuth 2.0) I had this thoughts:

1. First time, I would create a google account for the server and somehow retrieve token manually for the server, store it and refresh it every time I need access to my GAE services
2. Have some sort of private/public key authentication. I would create a private key for the server requesting the services and and store the public key in GAE application. Not sure if something like this exists.

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this issue? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into the [Client Credentials Grant part of the OAuth 2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)

This is how twitter does application-only auth, for example (see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)

That said, I personally think there are better ways of doing server-to-server authentication then the one provided by OAuth2 ([and I am not alone](http://hueniverse.com/2010/09/oauth-bearer-tokens-are-a-terrible-idea/)); I think that your point 2 is more solid alternative BUT security is something really difficult to implement correctly! I usually advice to not do it (and I avoid it myself, if possible).

So, if you find something reliable that implements this schema, good. Otherwise, stick to a solid OAuth2 library.